# Django - Calculate data in advance of opening a page

Tags: python, html, django, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to scrape some data that is going to be shown on a webpage.  However, the data is calculated every time the page is opened, and this causes the page to load for awhile before it is opened.  In Django, is there a simple method to calculate the data before the page is accessed so that it opens more quickly, and can also update the data every hour?

I was able to find this: https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/django-cron/latest/django-cron.pdf, but I am not sure if there is a more simple method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest making a python script and a regular cron job to pull the data into a Django model every hour. Then you can access the Django model normally.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use Django's inbuilt caching framework with a timeout of one hour. See 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/#basic-usage

One request per hour would still result in retrieval of new data, but it would greatly speed up the display of every other request in the hour, and you wouldn't have to deal with scheduled tasks.